# EF Core More Navigation properties from two tables

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am trying to create navigation properties for two table.

Here is the code.

```
    public class CourseMaster
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? TeamLeaderId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TeamLeaderId")]
    public StudentMaster TeamLeader { get; set; }

    public int? GroupLeaderId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("GroupLeaderId")]
    public StudentMaster GroupLeader { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StudentMaster> Students { get; set; }
}

public class StudentMaster
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int FirstSemCourseId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FirstSemCourseId")]
    public CourseMaster FirstSemCourse { get; set; }

    public int SecondSemCourseId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SecondSemCourseId")]
    public CourseMaster SecondSemCourse { get; set; }

    public int ThirdSemCourseId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ThirdSemCourseId")]
    public CourseMaster ThirdSemCourse { get; set; }


    public int CourseMasterId { get; set; }
    public CourseMaster Course { get; set; }

}

// Fluent API

        modelBuilder.Entity<StudentMaster>()
             .HasOne(p => p.Course)
             .WithMany(b => b.Students)
             .HasForeignKey(p => p.CourseMasterId);
```

But when i am creating migrations i am getting following error.

Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'CourseMaster.TeamLeader' of the type 'StudentMaster'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property from model.

Whether the procedure i am following is right or should i create intermediate class.

or how should i create class.

Any help are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You need to define the key for each entity and if you use data annotations you don't need to use fluent api

Comment: Sorry its my fault, actually both class inherits Entity class which as below. 

    public interface IEntity
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
        byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class Entity : IEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
    }


Then also i am getting same error.

Comment: i tried with adding [Key] 
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] to Id field. then also i am getting same error. any help are appreciated.